# The best way to store a specific type of information

Tags: database, data-structures, data-modeling

My question is, what is the best way to use a specific type of information in a database.

Let's suppose.

I have a table in a database like this:

Table: devices

```
id: AUTO_INCREMENT
model: INT (FK)
code: VARCHAR(30)
code_type: VARCHAR(20)
```

The **code_type's** value can be two types of information: TYPE1_ID or TYPE2_ID.

The column **code** assumes different values based on **code_type**.

If, the **code_type's** value is "TYPE1_ID", then the column **code** will have a specific value.

And, if the **code_type's** value is "TYPE2_ID", then the column **code** will have another value.

This is a way i can use to store informations.

The another way is:

Modify the type of data **code_type** to INT (FK). And i would need another table, which makes the reference.

Like this:

table: devices

```
id: AUTO_INCREMENT
model: INT (FK)
code: VARCHAR(30)
code_type: INT (FK)
```

The another table would be something like this:

table: code_types

```
id_type_code: INT
description: VARCHAR(40)
```

The column **id_type_code** is the ID of the type of information (TYPE1_ID or TYPE2_ID).
And the column description is about what type.

And finally, the question:

What is the best way to store my datas? Based on this context above.
Or, could you advice me another better way to store?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do and then the solution. Here you ask us to comment the solution without having explained what you are trying to model.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer depends on what you're doing with the data. Separating out the code_types table is a more normalized form - but if all your queries need to show the code_type description then you'll have to be joining constantly. Since it sounds like code_type has only two values have you considered using a bit/bool?

Comment: In this case, I don't need to show the code_type description. Description is just to know what it is. Yes! I can use boolean. But, imagine this case that i described. I'm using Java and I need to know in my code, what type it is. But, I don't know the best way to compare these values. When I have to query a device in my table **devices** and have a return, the best way is compare using String or Integer?
Thanks!

Comment: Integers will always be a faster comparison than strings.

Comment: If i make a query with a where clause using integer is more faster than String, right?

Comment: Yep, strings have to be compared character by character until one that's different is found. An integer is compared once.